# Загрузка файла с POST python

Tags: python, файлы, post

Сейчас получаю название файла с post запроса так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# (hash)print("Content-type: text/html")

import cgi

print()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print(form.getvalue('file'))
```

По ссылке скачиваю так:

```
url = "https://team.umonreal.ru/file/article/hype/2018/10/18/dbf7558babb75989321eaf9601ffd97d.jpg"
img = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
out = open("img.jpg", "wb")
out.write(img)
```

Не понимаю как принять с post запроса файл и скачать его

Comment: Не совсем понимаю ваш вопрос. Вроде же уже есть код для скачивания файла.

Comment: Мне нужно скачать файл переданный POST запросом